# How do I get MS Word to save color?

Tags: microsoft-word

Using MS Word 2013, how can I save a color so I can use it later when I open the document again?
[image: color screen shot]

Comment: Use the color for what? Font color, shape fill color, something else?

Comment: I want to save the color as an outline for a picture border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below shows how to change one of the default colors:

1. Go to the design tab
2. Select 'Colors'
3. Choose 'Customize colors'
4. Change one of the Accent colors to your desired color
5. Press save
6. Save document

[image: Original Colors]

[image: Office 2010 Colors]